# Not able to run my Java code from CMD but runs fine when I press the run button on the IDE

Tags: java

I need a bit of help I can't figure out the issue when I am running my java file from CMD it doesn't seem to output what is required. I have also made sure that I have specified the correct path to the file.

So this is what it is supposed to output / This is output when I click the run button in the IDE:
[image]

But when I try to compile it and run it from CMD its doesn't seem to output everything as can be seen below:
[image]

This is how the files are located.

CM1210 -> src -> Main.java
within the src folder I have Main.java / GPT3.txt / stopwords.txt

I have specified the files in the main method.

To see how the txt file look use the link below:

Here is a link to the GPT3 txt file: https://pastebin.com/a7Xv8ecC

Here is a link to the stopwords txt: https://pastebin.com/ZaAffYSK

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static int mergeSortCount = 0;

    public static ArrayList<String> removeStopwords(String GPT3, String Stopwords) {
        ArrayList<String> StopwordsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> GPT3Array = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {

            Scanner stopFile = new Scanner(new File(Stopwords));
            Scanner GPT3File = new Scanner(new File(GPT3));

            while(stopFile.hasNext()){

                StopwordsArray.add(stopFile.next());

            }

            stopFile.close();

            while(GPT3File.hasNext()){

                GPT3Array.add(GPT3File.next());

            }

            GPT3File.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("File error!");
        }

        GPT3Array.removeAll(StopwordsArray);
        return GPT3Array;
    }

    public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<String> GPT3Array) {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int wordsCounted = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < GPT3Array.size(); i++) {

            String item = GPT3Array.get(i);
            int j = i - 1;

            while(j >= 0 && GPT3Array.get(j).compareTo(item) > 0) {

                String temp = GPT3Array.get(j);
                GPT3Array.set(j, GPT3Array.get(j + 1));
                GPT3Array.set(j + 1, temp);
                j -= 1;

            }

            ++wordsCounted;

            if (wordsCounted % 100 == 0) {
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
                System.out.println("Time taken to sort " + wordsCounted + " words was " + timeTaken + " milliseconds.");
            }
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Words Sorted = " + wordsCounted + "\nTime Taken: " + timeTaken + " milliseconds.");
    }

    public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> GPT3Array) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        ArrayList<String> startArray = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> endArray = new ArrayList<>();

        int Start = 0;
        int End = GPT3Array.size();

        if (GPT3Array.size() <= 1) {
            return;
        } else {
            int midIndex = (Start + End) / 2;

            for (int i = Start; i < midIndex; i++) {
                startArray.add(GPT3Array.get(i));
            }
            for (int i = midIndex; i < End; i++) {
                endArray.add(GPT3Array.get(i));
            }


            mergeSort(startArray);
            mergeSort(endArray);

            merge(GPT3Array, startArray, endArray);

        }

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;

        if (mergeSortCount % 100 == 0) {
            System.out.println("The time taken to sort " + mergeSortCount + " words was " + timeTaken + " nano seconds.");
        }

    }

    public static void merge(ArrayList<String> GPT3Array, ArrayList<String> startArray, ArrayList<String> endArray) {
        int startPointer = 0;
        int endPointer = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (startPointer < startArray.size() || endPointer < endArray.size()) {

            mergeSortCount++;

            if (startPointer < startArray.size() && endPointer < endArray.size()) {
                if (startArray.get(startPointer).compareTo(endArray.get(endPointer)) < 0) {
                    GPT3Array.set(i, startArray.get(startPointer));
                    startPointer++;
                    i++;
                } else {
                    GPT3Array.set(i, endArray.get(endPointer));
                    endPointer++;
                    i++;
                }
            }   else if (startPointer < startArray.size()) {
                GPT3Array.set(i, startArray.get(startPointer));
                startPointer++;
                i++;
            } else {
                GPT3Array.set(i, endArray.get(endPointer));
                endPointer++;
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filenameGPT3 = "./GPT3.txt";
        String filenameStop = "./stopwords.txt";


        ArrayList<String> GPT3Array = new ArrayList<>(removeStopwords(filenameGPT3, filenameStop));


        try {
            insertionSort(GPT3Array);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Insertion Sort Error");
        }

        try {
            mergeSort(GPT3Array);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Insertion Sort Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas or reasons why this may be happening?

Comment: The code you've shown does *not* output the stuff the text you've shown, so please provide a complete [mre]

Comment: I am updating it